# laravel prefil form inputs from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, default-value

Hi I'm using laravel forms.

```
{!! Form::text('product_name', null, array('class' => 'form-control date_pick')) !!}
```

Is there a way to set this default input from controller?. Think we can do it with Flash but I couldn't find an example. I want to take vlues from a model and prepopulate.

```
$products = Products::all();
```

It would be great if someone know how to do this. What is the easiest way to do it?

Comment: You can use [form model binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#form-model-binding) for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll chk it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with a basic edit route where you simply use:

In ModelController you would call the edit page:

```
public function edit(ModelName $model) {

    return view('name.of.the.blade.view', compact('model')); // if using compact then without dollar symbol
}
```

In blade view simply make the form with all the input fields you have for that model:

```
{!! Form::model($model, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['model.update', $model->id],]) !!}

    Now all the form fields will have the values from that model.


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And the edit and update route (inside routes/web.php) would be like this:

```
Route::get('/model/{model}/edit', 'ModelController@edit')->name('model.edit');
Route::patch('/model/{model}', 'ModelController@update')->name('model.update');
```

Comment: is $model object of the model class?

Comment: Thanks bro and think {!! Form::model($model it should be. Really sorry if wrong